# HTC OpenSense SDK repository.xml url link

Tags: android

Anyone knows HTC OpenSense SDK repository.xml url link?I'm not ok to download HTC OpenSense SDK.After downloaded file,I got only incomplete damage zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Direct repository link not available. Just follow the steps.

1. Download HTC Open Sense [from here](http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/download-instructions) (Requires registration) Just a 10 MB ZIp file
2. Unzip download to reveal 5 files, README.txt, 2 add-on zip files and 2 corresponding repository xml files used for installing the and tablet add-on extensions.
   (Do not unzip the extension Add-on zip files, these are installed using the Android SDK and AVD Manager.)

   The following steps illustrate installing the phone add-on extension. The same applies to the tablet add-on extension.

Click on Add Add-on Site for the HTC SDK Add-ons and specify a file:// URL pointing to the xml file for the Add-on site.

For example, on Windows:
file:///c://addon_htc_phone.xml

Now just create your AVD for the HTC Phone extension and enjoy !!

Answer (score 1):

You can add the following repository to the user defined sites in the AVD manager.

```
http://dl.htcdev.com/apis
```

You can get more details at HTC's own site: http://www.htcdev.com/devcenter/opensense-sdk/download-install